# How to call servlet from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

Servlet Configuration in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
    <display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
    <servlet-name>DataEntry</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ctn.origin.connection.DataEntry</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DataEntry</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dataentry</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function unloadEvt() {

        document.location.href='/test/dataentry';

    }
</script>
```

But using this javascript can't call my servlet.

Is there any error ? how to call servlet ?

Comment: did you try loading the servlet by typing the url into the browser's address bar?

Comment: I'll assume that the double double quote on the end of the URL is just a careless typo. Please fix it in your question if true.

Comment: yes i am call while submit form and work perfetct. Now i want to call it onunload event of javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/testmail/dataentry", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is **not guaranteed** to work in all browsers. It also depends on the network speed between the client and the server.

Answer (score 15):

From your original question:

> ```
> document.location.href="/dataentry";
> ```

The leading slash `/` in the URL will take you to the domain root.

So if the JSP page containing the script is running on

> http://localhost:8080/contextname/page.jsp

then your `location` URL will point to

> http://localhost:8080/dataentry

But you actually need

> http://localhost:8080/contextname/dataentry

So, fix the URL accordingly

```
document.location.href = 'dataentry';
// Or
document.location.href = '/contextname/dataentry';
// Or
document.location.href = '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/dataentry';
```

---

Apart from that, the function name `unloadEvt()` suggests that you're invoking the function during `onunload` or `onbeforeunload`. If this is true, then you should look for another solution. The request is **not guaranteed** to ever reach the server. This depends on among others the browser used. How to solve it properly depends on the sole functional requirement which is not clear from the question.

Comment: I want if user fill incomplete delete and close browser then that much detail enter into database.

Comment: OK, then solve it accordingly so that you don't need to hack on the `onunload`. If you can't figure how to solve it properly, feel free to ask a new question with the **functional requirement clearly elaborated**.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this if you are using jQuery. It's simple:

```
<script>
    $(window).unload(function() {
        document.location.href='/test/dataentry';
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How exactly does this make difference as opposed to `window.onload = function() { ... }`?

Comment: you are using onload. I'm referring to unload. This will capture the unload event and forward the user to /test/dataentry