# Run Java method in Javascript in Freemarker template

Tags: javascript, java, html, freemarker

I would like to run method over my Java object in Freemaker template but in Javascript. Could be also directly in Freemarker but I need to run it on click.

I have issue that following method doesnt run:

```
actual_id.setActual_id(variable) ;
```

And I have following Java code:

```
Setting actual_id= new Setting("-");

Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("items", items);
data.put("actual_id", actual_id);

public Setting(String actual_id) {
    this.actual_id = actual_id;
}

public String getActual_id() {
    return actual_id;
}

public void setActual_id(String actual_id) {
    this.actual_id = actual_id;
}
```

This is my Freemaker template:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>function myFunction(variable) {
alert(variable);
actual_id.setActual_id(variable) ;
location.reload();}
</script>

<#list items as item>
<p>${item.name}: ${item.id} <button type="button" id="${item.id}" onclick=myFunction("${item.id}") >Details</button>
    </#list>
```

**EDIT1:**

I am also trying something like this:

```
onclick="${actual_id.setActual_id(item.id)}"
```

but cannot trigger activity from onclick.

**EDIT2:**

I already almost found solution. Following code executes Java method, I just need to figure out how to quote "variable" to load javasript value into it.

```
function myFunction(variable) {
    alert(variable);
    var idd ="${actual_id.setActual_id(variable)}";//here variable value needed
    alert(idd);
    location.reload();
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I made some progress, put it into EDIT2 and now I just need to get value of the javascript variable within freemaker expression.

Comment: Look like what you have done is correct .Did you get values in the map?

Comment: Yes everything works, just I need to get String value from variable "variable" in the freemaker expression: "${actual_id.setActual_id(variable)}" -> here "variable" is recognized as freemaker variable but I need it as javascript variable.

Comment: You can't do `variable` because there is no such thing .

Comment: So how could I load javascript variable into freemaker variable?
Something like this:
<#assign freemaker_variable = js_variable>

Comment: Your problem is items is in the list so you have to pass dynamically . In js actualid pass like this  `${actual_id}.setActual_id(variable)` and  `onclick=myFunction('${item.id}')` hope this is sufficient

Comment: Thanks, now it generates following html but doesnt execute js function at all: 
 var idd = urlpackage$Settinga@2c6e22c6.setActual_id(variable);

Comment: It's because you have not having string. Perhaps you can check what setting objects contain

Comment: Whats not String? my "variable" is a string. Also "setActual_id sets" sets variable "object.actual_id" which is a string and it also returns string. :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181930/discussion-between-jokuja-and-manfromnowhere).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quote from the **Apache FreeMarker** Project front-page:
(https://freemarker.apache.org/)

> What is Apache FreeMarker™?
>
> Apache FreeMarker™ is a template engine: a Java library to generate
>   text output (HTML web pages, e-mails, configuration files, source
>   code, etc.) based on templates and changing data. Templates are
>   written in the FreeMarker Template Language (FTL), which is a simple,
>   specialized language (not a full-blown programming language like PHP).
>   Usually, a general-purpose programming language (like Java) is used to
>   prepare the data (issue database queries, do business calculations).
>   Then, Apache FreeMarker displays that prepared data using templates.
>   In the template you are focusing on how to present the data, and
>   outside the template you are focusing on what data to present.
>
> Figure [**Photo/Image Not Posted**]
>
> This approach is often referred to as the MVC (Model View Controller)
>   pattern, and is particularly popular for dynamic web pages. It helps
>   in separating web page designers (HTML authors) from developers (Java
>   programmers usually). Designers won't face complicated logic in
>   templates, and can change the appearance of a page without programmers
>   having to change or recompile code.
>
> While FreeMarker was originally created for generating HTML pages in
>   MVC web application frameworks, ** it isn't bound to servlets or HTML
>   or anything web-related.** It's used in non-web application
>   environments as well.

https://freemarker.apache.org/

**I, myself, program Java & JavaScript web-servers on Google Cloud Server all day long.**  The only way to make a JavaScript function talk to a Java Function is through an **HTTP GET / POST** call to a **Java-Servlet** or, also, an old-school **JSP Page**.  Though it says (explicity) right on the top-level domain page of the website that "Freemarker is not bound to Servlets" - that actually means the software classes / package does not have to run inside of a web-environment at all - perhaps on your desktop computer without a web-browser.

**What I do know with an extremely high degree of certainty** is that communication between the client (on a web-browser) and a server (a web-server) is always done through HTTP GET / POST requests.  JSON, AJAX are common for higher communicating large amounts of data.  If you expect a JavaScript method to make a call to a Java Class on the back-end, you will need to include a Servlet or JSP class - and the whole 9 yards to boot.

**NOTE:** I have not used Apache FreeMarker, but I program Java/JavaScript all day long.  Judge accordingly!  According to the Apache web-site, FreeMarker is of assistance in "programatically or automatically generating the HTML for pages" (which is what C# is good at) - which is actually something I do for my web-site, often, but (alas!) I don't use Apache's product.  What that means is FreeMarker can help the generating of HTML more efficiently using Java Classes on the back-end server side ...

> **But the rules of how Java and Java-Script communicate have not
>   changed...**

Long story short - you must include JavaScript calls such as:

- [calling a java servlet from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028490/calling-a-java-servlet-from-javascript)
- [How to send request from javascript to servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490370/how-to-send-request-from-javascript-to-servlet)
- [How to call servlet from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218237/how-to-call-servlet-from-javascript)